# Evaluating $\int\frac{ {\operatorname d}x}{1-x^3}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to find $$\int\frac{{\operatorname d}x}{1-x^3}?$$

Is it possible by sine or cosine functions?

It is not easy to calculate it by reparametrization.

Comment: Your function isn't clear. Use LaTeX (Math Jax) to write mathematics in this site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 
$$1-x^3=(1-x)(1+x+x^2).$$

Then, you'll find
$$\frac{1}{1-x^3}=\frac{1/3}{1-x}+\frac{(1/3)x+(2/3)}{x^2+x+1}.$$

Comment: The numerator of the second term in the partial fraction expansion should be $(1/3)x+2/3$.

Comment: Oh that's right!:D  Can i ask you some formula about it?

Comment: @AméricoTavares: Thanks! I edited it.

Comment: @user120638: of course. you can ask anything here.

Comment: Umm... About the right formula, how can i solve the integral? That must be the multiple 2x+1(numerator)

Comment: @mathlove: ... About the right formula, how can i solve the integral? That must be the multiple 2x+1(numerator)

Comment: @user120638 Lots and lots of partial fractions and then when you get to a good point trig substitute like no tomorrow. Ill spoil it for you though, it doesn't look pretty.

Comment: (1/3)x+(2/3) / x^2+x+1  how this formula integrated?

Comment: @user120638: You can use $$\frac{(1/6)(x^2+x+1)^\prime}{x^2+x+1}+\frac{(2/3)-(1/6)}{x^2+x+1}$$

Comment: So... I don't know well about $$frac\{1}{x^2+x+1}$$

Comment: You can use $$\frac{1}{(x+(1/2))^2+(3/4)}=\cdots=\frac{(4/3)}{((2/\sqrt 3)x+(1/\sqrt 3))^2+1}$$Then set $(2/\sqrt 3)x+(1/\sqrt 3)=\tan\theta$

Comment: @mathlove Oh... thank you! That's possible by derivative of arctan~

Comment: @user120638: You are welcome!